# How to make state provider catch all urls and their query paramters

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

```
$stateProvider
    .state('all', {
        /* This matches any url, and exposes the path to $stateParams with the name myPath */
        url: 'myPath*',
        resolve: {
            ...
```

Imagine the url is:

```
"something/blah"
```

`$stateParams` contains this whole query.

But when the url is:

```
"something/blah?user=blah"
```

`$stateParams` contains only the original url part `"something/blah"`

How can i make it acknowledge the url being different even based on query paramters?

Answer (score 0):

```
$stateProvider 
    .state('all', {
            url: 'something/blah?user',
        })
```

Try, you can now use $stateParams in a controler.

```
$stateParams.user
```

Comment: I really need to include all query parameters. so not just "user" but in fact catch all *